# Two sum data structure problems

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I built a data structure for two sum question. In this data structure I built add and find method. 
add - Add the number to an internal data structure.
find - Find if there exists any pair of numbers which sum is equal to the value.
For example:

```
add(1); add(3); add(5);
find(4) // return true
find(7) // return false
```

the following is my code, so what is wrong with this code?

 http://www.lintcode.com/en/problem/two-sum-data-structure-design/
this is the test website, some cases could not be passed

```
public class TwoSum {
    private List<Integer> sets;
    TwoSum() {
        this.sets = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }
    // Add the number to an internal data structure.
    public void add(int number) {
        // Write your code here
        this.sets.add(number);
    }

    // Find if there exists any pair of numbers which sum is equal to the value.
    public boolean find(int value) {
        // Write your code here
        Collections.sort(sets);
        for (int i = 0; i < sets.size(); i++) {
            if (sets.get(i) > value) break;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < sets.size(); j++) {
                if (sets.get(i) + sets.get(j) == value) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your code not working? if so where or what seems to be the issue.

Comment: http://www.lintcode.com/en/problem/two-sum-data-structure-design/. This is the test website. And I cannot pass some tests of it.

Comment: @WBLee don't link to a site that requires a login. If you can't say which test-cases aren't passing *in the question itself* then you probably shouldn't be asking on StackOverflow.

Comment: It is  a huge input test case. and the output value of it is not good. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be anything wrong with your code.

However a coding challenge could possibly require a more performant solution. (You check every item against every item, which would take O(N^2)).

The best solution to implement `find`, is using a `HashMap`, which would take O(N). It's explained more in detail [here](https://www.fitcoding.com/2014/03/05/find-pairs-that-equal-to-a-specific-sum-in-an-array/).